# Twilio Voice in Traditional/Multi-Page Web App

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

We have a traditional web app with multiple pages, within which we are trying to implement Twilio Voice.
It is written in Asp.Net WebForms, using the [Twilio JS SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript) and [TaskRouter.js](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk).

As you would expect, uer interactions cause frequent page reloads and navigations, which would drop any call in progress (obviously not a desirable outcome).

To get around this, we have been implementing Twilio Voice via a dedicated phone page which is permanently open on the user's machine.
This holds the twilio device/workers/etc and handles all the specifics of communicating with Twilio, while other pages in the app communicate with that page via a [broadcast-channel](https://npmjs.com/broadcast-channel) to provide phone control from any page.

The problem we have discovered today is that browsers (or ay least Firefox) don't seem to allow access to audio devices until the requesting page is focused.
As such, the call doesn't actually start until the phone page is clicked to bring it into focus. This is true for both dialling out (where it won't initiate the call) and for accepting calls (where the popout controls just don't respond).

This is a reasonable and unsertandable security measure in my view, but it does make our specific use case pretty difficult.

I am struggling to come up with a solution to this issue. So far I have these options in mind, although none of them seem particularly appealing:

1. Have the phone page open ready for incoming calls, then close it and reopen it when the user requests to dial out - this would allow for dialling out, but not for accepting incoming calls from a separate page. Additionally, depending on user settings, the new window may not necessarily be the focused window.
2. Initiate/accept the call from the user's current window, then temporarily place the call on hold while the device is torn down and built up again whenever the user naviagates away. This would obviously have a degredential effect on the user experience.
3. Implement and maintain an equivalent of the phone page as a desktop app installed on the user's computer, which the webpage would communicate with via a websocket (or equivalent). We would prefer to avoid this as it would increase maintenance and decrease usability.
4. I don't think this is possible, but perhaps running most of the twilio logic in an extension [`SharedWorker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SharedWorker) and switching audio contexts to the current window when the user switches between them?

Does anyone have any experience or advice which would be helpful in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this without a suitable SPA, perhaps creating a landing page with two iFrames that sit next to one another--one for the WebForms (shudder) app and one for the Twilio page. Sending data between the two might get tricky, but you already have the solution for that with the broadcast-channel it sounds like. I hate to recommend iFrames as a solution in this day and age, but you're not going to get around the DOM loading problem otherwise (after all, you're using a technology created in 2002, so why not supplement it with something from the 90's?). This may not be the best answer, but I earnestly believe not using WebForms is the best one (unless it's only serving the boilerplate, but even then, yuck) and you're probably too far along to consider that option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).